# Running Pg+Java on remote cluster with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to run a simple pig code in java using eclipse on my windows machine.I am launching this code cloudera VM.

Here is code that i am trying to execute

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;

public class PigConnect{
           public static void main(String[] args) {
           try {

            PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("mapreduce");
            runIdQuery(pigServer, "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/myFile.txt");

           }
           catch(Exception e) 
           {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
        }
        public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer, String inputFile) throws IOException {
           pigServer.registerQuery("A = load 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/myFile.txt' using PigStorage(':');");
           pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate $0 as id;");
           pigServer.store("B", "idout");
           System.out.println("Success");

           }
        }
```

I added hdfs-site.xml,yarn-site.xml,core-site.xml,mapred-site.xml in resource folder in eclipse.Added all required jar in project.

While running code i am getting below error.

```
Error during parsing. Unable to check name hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/shashi
```

shashi is my windows user name which it is taking by default.How should change it use hdfs user?